# Fluent API EF tutorial mistake

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, extension-methods, ef-fluent-api

I am referring to the tutorial found here:

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Given

```
public class Student
{
  public int StudentId { get; set; }
  public string StudentName { get; set; }

  //StdId is not following code first conventions name
  public int StdId { get; set; }

  public virtual Standard Standard { get; set; }
}

public class Standard
{
  public int StandardId { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong. I think this is wrong

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Standard>()
  .HasMany<Student>(s => s.Students)
  .WithRequired(s => s.Standard)
  .HasForeignKey(s => s.StdId);
```

and this is correct

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
  .HasRequired<Standard>(s => s.Standard)
  .WithMany(s => s.Students)
  .HasForeignKey(s => s.StdId);
```

Because StdId is the foreign key of Student and not Standard.

But the article says they are the same.

Please let me know if I am right.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out after playing around with the code.

The two fluent API's are the same and it doesn't matter whether you traverse from Student or Standard.

The reason being there is only one foreign key here and that is StdId.